# checking at least one check box with different names

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have three checkboxes on my page. All three have different names. I want at least one  check box to be checked. I saw several post that validates one check box to be required, but in my situation, all the check boxes have different names. below is my code:

```
 <form asp-action="Edit">
 <div class="form-group row">
                 <div class="col">
                        <input asp-for="HREmployee" type="checkbox" class="require-one validate-checkbox-oneormore" value="1"  />    Human Resources Employee
                  

                    </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input asp-for="ManagementEmployee" type="checkbox" class="require-one validate1" value="2"/>    Management


                    </div>
                </div>
                     <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <input asp-for="StaffEmployee" type="checkbox" class="require-one validate1" value="3"  />    Staff Employee


                    </div>

 <input  type="submit" id="myBtn1" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"  />
```

I want user to check at least one check box. below s what I tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod('validate-validate1', function (value) {
        return $('.require-one:checked').size() != 0; }, 'need a value');

    jQuery('#Edit').validate({});
});
```

Form gets summitted even if I don't check any checkbox.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.is(':checked')` to verify that at least one of the matched elements was checked. If this is not the case, call `event.preventDefault()` to stop the form submission.

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  const $error = $('.error', this).text('');
  if (!$('input.require-one', this).is(':checked')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $error.text('Please check at least one box');
  }
});
```

```css
.error{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form asp-action="Edit">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
      <input asp-for="HREmployee" type="checkbox" class="require-one validate-checkbox-oneormore" value="1" /> Human Resources Employee
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
      <input asp-for="ManagementEmployee" type="checkbox" class="require-one validate1" value="2" /> Management
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col">
      <input asp-for="StaffEmployee" type="checkbox" class="require-one validate1" value="3" /> Staff Employee
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="myBtn1" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
  </div>
  <p class="error"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: I dont see the required message when I run your code snippet. Can I see a requird message too

Comment: @rimi What do you mean by "required message"?

Comment: when I click the submit button without checking any checkbox, I dont see any required message saying something like at least one check box is required

Comment: You can always a validation message in a `<p>` element, for example. Or do you want something like the browser's default required message?

Comment: <p> element? Can you give me an example